# How to download firebase storage files

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

as of right now I am using images currently in my assets folder, and is it definitely creating memory/app size issues.

I uploaded the photos to firebase storage in their related storage references and now I am a little stuck on how to download each image from the storage from here.

Here is my current code

```swift
// Trend Model

enum Gender { case male, female }

struct Trend {
    var name: String
    var details: String
    var image: UIImage?
    var gender : Gender
    var childValue: String
}

// Create trend
let femaleTrends = [

Trend(name: "Animal Prints", details: "Details will go here!", image: UIImage(named: "AnimalPrintW"), gender: .female, childValue: "animalprints"),

Trend(name: "Green", details: "Details will go here",image: UIImage(named: "Green"),gender: .female, childValue: "green")
]

 let maleTrends = [

Trend(name: "Animal Prints", details: "Details will go here!",image:UIImage(named: "AnimalPrintM"),gender: .male , childValue: "animalprints"),

....

]
```

Here is another view controller that holds the a collection view that displays a list of trends

```swift
//Display the current trend image place holder and labels
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homeViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CurrentTrendsCell

        switch selectedSegmentIndex {
        case 0: cell.trendsLabel.text = femaleTrends[indexPath.row].name
        cell.trendsImageView.image = femaleTrends[indexPath.row].image


        case 1: cell.trendsLabel.text = maleTrends[indexPath.row].name
        cell.trendsImageView.image = maleTrends[indexPath.row].image

        default: break

        }
        return cell


    }
```

I read through the firebase storage doc and tried some practice code

```swift
let animalPrintRef = STORAGE_FEMALETREND_IMAGES_REF.child("AnimalPrints.jpeg").getData(maxSize: 1) { (data, error) in
      if let error = error {
            // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
          } else {
            // AnimalPrints.jpeg" is returned

             // This is the image I need
             let image = UIImage(data: data!)

          }
}
```

I understand it but I'm not sure how to grab the image data for each `trend` and implement it into the `image` in `Trend`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use firebase storage to save images and put the image link into your database.

```
typealias blockCompletedWith = (Bool, String) -> Void

func uploadProfileImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0)
        let path = "folderName/imagename.jpeg"
        self.uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: imageData!, path: path, blockCompletedWith: { (isSuccess, urlStr) in
            Utility.stopActivityIndicator()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                if isSuccess {
                    print(urlStr)
                }
                else {
                    print("Error in uploading Image")
                }
            }
        })
    }
```

-----------uploadImageToFirebaseStorage Method------------

```
//path: folder name if any followed by name of image
func uploadImageToFirebaseStorage(data: Data, path: String, blockCompletedWith: @escaping blockCompletedWith) {
        let metadata = StorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        let store = Storage.storage()
        let storeRef = store.reference().child(path)
        let _ = storeRef.putData(data, metadata: metadata) { (metadata, error) in
            guard let _ = metadata else {
                print("error occured: \(error.debugDescription)")
                blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                return
            }

            storeRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {
                    blockCompletedWith(true, urlText)
                }
                else {
                    blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                }
            })
        }
    }
```

In this func "uploadImageToFirebaseStorage" you get a link of firebase uploaded content and with the help of the link, you can access the uploaded content.

Part of the function where you will get the link(you can save this url into your database for reference):

```
storeRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if let urlText = url?.absoluteString {
                    blockCompletedWith(true, urlText)
                }
                else {
                    blockCompletedWith(false, "")
                }
            })
```

Hope that helps!

---

If you have uploaded images manually you can get the url via clicking that particular content...in the right side a window will come where you can get the link for your resource.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed and educational answer! I will implement now